# Javascript object retained by pure function context

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

In a method of a class I did this:

```
this.editor = monaco.editor.create(this.elm, {
    cursorWidth: 2, cursorBlinking: 'solid',
    wordBasedSuggestions: false,
    rulers: [80],
    wordWrap: 'bounded', wordWrapColumn: 80, wrappingIndent: 'indent',
    contextmenu: false,
    dragAndDrop: false,
    folding: false,
    glyphMargin: true,
    language: 'sigmet',
    lineNumbers: n => n === 1 ? 'H' : n - 1,
    minimap: {enabled: false},
    multiCursorModifier: 'ctrlCmd',
    renderWhitespace: 'all',
})
```

When inspecting memory with chrome, an instance of a class is retained by the context of the function which is in the lineNumbers property of the object passed to the create function of monaco.editor.

Transforming the arrow function into a regular function does not fix the problem.

Moving the function to the beginning of the file like this fixed the problem:

```
function lineNumbers(n) {
    return n === 1 ? 'H' : n - 1
}
```

So my question is why does a pure function prevent garbage collection?

Comment: It's not even close to clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Everything is in the title. This is not normal. A pure function should not even have a context.

Comment: Sounds like the compiler just doesn't optimize this case well. It sees a nested function, and compiles it as a closure rather than a pure function.